# why is my printf doing this?

Tags: c, printf

it seems like such a silly thing to ask but i seriously don't know why this is happening. Could be that it's almost 5am and i'm still doing this but..

It should print -CA but why when i compile it, it is printing

```
-
CA?
```

instead of -CA, there isn't a '\n' anywhere in sight. 
Can you guys think of anything logical that would explain it?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

int check = 0;
char *thing = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));

strcpy(char, "CA");

some code..

   do{

    more code...

    if(condition== 1) {
            more code.... 
            if(check == 0) { 
                printf("-");
                check++;
            }


    if (some conditon != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",thing);
    }while(condition)


return 0;
```

}

Comment: How are you expecting `printf("%s\n",thing);` to know how many characters to print?

Comment: What David wants to say is that your `thing` is not null terminated.

Comment: Should be `char thing[] = "CA";` As for the newline, post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem, and then we'll talk.

Comment: It was actually a string and i malloc-ed it to 2, sorry, i typed that as i was lazy to type out the malloc syntax, what i'm asking is there a logical reason as to why it would print on a new line when there is no \n?

Comment: @JackYeoh you know, when you have undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: @JackYeoh "It was actually a string and i malloc-ed it"... post the acutal (but minimal) code here, otherwise you are just wasting our time.

Comment: @JackYeoh The newline is coming from the `...` part of your code.

Comment: You don't allocate enough space for the terminating null, and please don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: .. or use `sizeof(char)` because it is `1` by definition.

Comment: Please copy/paste when posing the code you're having trouble with so bogus stuff like `strcpy(char, "CA");` doesn't end up needlessly confusing the issue.

Comment: It's all a bit convoluted anyway. Why not use `char thing[] = "CA";` which does what your code is struggling over?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't allocate enough space for your string. Every string has a null terminator, so a 2-character string needs 3 bytes in the array. Your `strcpy()` is writing outside the bounds of the `thing` array when it copies the null byte, which results in undefined behavior.

Use

```
char *thing = malloc(3);
```

You can also use `strdup()`, which makes a copy of a string in dynamic memory, automatically allocating enough space based on the length of the original string.

```
char *thing = strdup("CA");
```

Comment: Even better might be `char* thing = strdup("CA");`

Answer (score 1):

`printf` prints a null terminated string to the `stdout`. if the sting is not null terminated the `printf` will go on printing garbage to the `stdout` till a null terminator is met
so you should all one to your character array

`char thing[3] = {'C','A',0};`

now `printf` will print

```
-
CA
```

Comment: Code is amiss earlier at `strcpy(char, "CA");`, long before the `printf()`.